# Select dropdown in modal using Angular 1.29 and latest Chrome 47

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome

We are having an issue with a regular `<select>` dropdown located inside a modal used by an Angular component. This previously worked, but now with the upgrade to Chrome 47 does not anymore -- there are absolutely no errors generated on the javascript console, it is completely silent.

Moving the dropdown outside of the modal into a regular page works, so it is specifically related to being located inside a modal, and specifically something within an Angular component.

Angular 1.29
Chrome 47

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: some code or fiddle?

Comment: Is it html select dropdown or angular-bootstrap or other ?

Comment: It is a plain vanilla html select dropdown with no angular. I can follow-up later with some code but wanted to put the question out to see if anyone has encountered it since the newest Chrome upgrade.

Comment: what does "it does not work" actually mean? does the dropdown have no values? can you not select any options? does it pick a different option from what you select? being that it's "inside a modal", is something in the modal overlapping the dropdown at a higher z index? you haven't really given anything to go on here.

Comment: having the same issue here, although we have a pretty old angular version running (1.0.8).

Comment: The issue is reported here, please up vote if you have the same issue.
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=565132

Comment: This is that exact problem reported, thanks @Kungen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was the bug described here: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=565132

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue with Angular 1.26.  I updated to 1.4.5 and it works correctly.

All I had to do to upgrade was add the following script tag to my index.html file.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Same for me. I've used angular version 1.2.9 and now updated to version 1.4.8.

Luckily for me there was no breaking changes that caused any issues on my site at least.

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be specifically with the ng-options directive for the select element. If you instead use an embedded option element with an ng-repeat, those work fine. Granted, that's only as long as your options are not dynamic...

This doesn't work:

```
<select ng-options="item in data.myList"></select>
```

This does:

```
<select>
    <option ng-repeat="item in data.myList">{{item.text}}</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution I've found is to download fresh **1.2.x (legacy)** version (which is at the moment 1.2.29) from [angular website](https://angularjs.org/).

Because in some cases stable 1.4.x version is not compatible with applications that was previously written with 1.2.

Answer (score 0):

For a quick turn around we upgraded angular version to v1.2.17 which specifically has the fix for this issue and it went well in production. However for being safe side its always best to keep upgrading angular to its latest of its league, more or less frequently. (Currently, v1.2.29 is the latest of v1.2 league). 
I tried upgrading the chrome browser to 48 beta and it was also not solving the issue ( So we can't even expect the next version of Chrome will get the fix ).  The best solution stands to be upgrading it.